# Identity ASP Net Root Element Missing

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, entity-framework, identity

I've taken a C# project from a colleague whom is now an ex colleague. He moved on to better things. with that said i'm having some trouble disecting his code and enabling the Identity login for said project.

I've researched and found many fixes but neither of which get me past a final step.

the project uses EF and so i created the new connection string direct to the DB where the tables exists and updated the IndentityModel.cs file to suit

Web.config

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=SERVER;Initial Catalog=DB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=USERNAME;Password=PASSWORD;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  <add name="Production_MonitorEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.ProductionModel.csdl|res://*/Models.ProductionModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.ProductionModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=SERVER;initial catalog=DB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=USERNAME;Password=PASSWORD;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework;Connection Timeout=60&quot;"  providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

This is the IndentityModel.cs

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
    }
```

When i register as a new user, i receive the following error within Register.aspx.cs

```
IdentityResult result = manager.Create(user, Password.Text);
```

An exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Root element is missing.

my register class looks like this

```
  public partial class Register : Page
    {
        protected void CreateUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var manager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
            var signInManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
            var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = Email.Text, Email = Email.Text };
            IdentityResult result = manager.Create(user, Password.Text);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                //string code = manager.GenerateEmailConfirmationToken(user.Id);
                //string callbackUrl = IdentityHelper.GetUserConfirmationRedirectUrl(code, user.Id, Request);
                //manager.SendEmail(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>.");

                signInManager.SignIn( user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
                IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"], Response);
            }
            else 
            {
                ErrorMessage.Text = result.Errors.FirstOrDefault();
            }
        }
    }
```

and the full stack trace is

```
[XmlException: Root element is missing.]
   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e) +72
   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent() +5340358
   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read() +163
   System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(XmlReader reader, LoadOptions options) +44
   System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(Stream stream, LoadOptions options) +64
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Edm.ModelCompressor.Decompress(Byte[] bytes) +86
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.History.HistoryRepository.GetLastModel(String& migrationId, String& productVersion, String contextKey) +1016
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.QueryForModel(DatabaseExistenceState existenceState) +38
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.ModelCompatibilityChecker.CompatibleWithModel(InternalContext internalContext, ModelHashCalculator modelHashCalculator, Boolean throwIfNoMetadata, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState) +56
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.CompatibleWithModel(Boolean throwIfNoMetadata, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState) +54
   System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context) +124
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.<>c__DisplayClassf`1.<CreateInitializationAction>b__e() +76
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action) +60
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization() +395
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.<InitializeDatabase>b__4(InternalContext c) +11
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input) +110
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action) +214
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase() +97
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +28
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +53
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Include(String path) +18
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.Include(String path) +66
   System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.Include(IQueryable`1 source, String path) +130
   System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.Include(IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 path) +181
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore`6.GetUserAggregateAsync(Expression`1 filter) +259
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore`6.FindByNameAsync(String userName) +536
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager`2.FindByNameAsync(String userName) +56
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.<ValidateUserName>d__4.MoveNext() +376
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.<ValidateAsync>d__0.MoveNext() +247
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.<CreateAsync>d__0.MoveNext() +568
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.<CreateAsync>d__d.MoveNext() +483
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.AsyncHelper.RunSync(Func`1 func) +281
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManagerExtensions.Create(UserManager`2 manager, TUser user, String password) +120
   ProductionMonitor.Account.Register.CreateUser_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\newmanr\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ProductionMonitor\Account\Register.aspx.cs:19
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9669962
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +108
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +12
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +15
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3562
```

and then when i try to login using a user that already exists in the database of users i receive the same xml root element is missing

An exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Root element is missing.

at this line

```
 var result = signinManager.PasswordSignIn(Email.Text, Password.Text, RememberMe.Checked, shouldLockout: false);
```

this is the full login cs file

```
 public partial class Login : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RegisterHyperLink.NavigateUrl = "Register";
            // Enable this once you have account confirmation enabled for password reset functionality
            //ForgotPasswordHyperLink.NavigateUrl = "Forgot";
            OpenAuthLogin.ReturnUrl = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"];
            var returnUrl = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]);
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
            {
                RegisterHyperLink.NavigateUrl += "?ReturnUrl=" + returnUrl;
            }
        }

        protected void LogIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsValid)
            {
                // Validate the user password
                var manager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
                var signinManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationSignInManager>();

                // This doen't count login failures towards account lockout
                // To enable password failures to trigger lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
                var result = signinManager.PasswordSignIn(Email.Text, Password.Text, RememberMe.Checked, shouldLockout: false);

                switch (result)
                {
                    case SignInStatus.Success:
                        IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"], Response);
                        break;
                    case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                        Response.Redirect("/Account/Lockout");
                        break;
                    case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                        Response.Redirect(String.Format("/Account/TwoFactorAuthenticationSignIn?ReturnUrl={0}&RememberMe={1}", 
                                                        Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"],
                                                        RememberMe.Checked),
                                          true);
                        break;
                    case SignInStatus.Failure:
                    default:
                        FailureText.Text = "Invalid login attempt";
                        ErrorMessage.Visible = true;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and it provides me with this stack trace

```
[XmlException: Root element is missing.]
   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e) +72
   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent() +5340358
   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read() +163
   System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(XmlReader reader, LoadOptions options) +44
   System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(Stream stream, LoadOptions options) +64
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Edm.ModelCompressor.Decompress(Byte[] bytes) +86
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.History.HistoryRepository.GetLastModel(String& migrationId, String& productVersion, String contextKey) +1016
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.QueryForModel(DatabaseExistenceState existenceState) +38
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.ModelCompatibilityChecker.CompatibleWithModel(InternalContext internalContext, ModelHashCalculator modelHashCalculator, Boolean throwIfNoMetadata, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState) +56
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.CompatibleWithModel(Boolean throwIfNoMetadata, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState) +54
   System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context) +124
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.<>c__DisplayClassf`1.<CreateInitializationAction>b__e() +76
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action) +60
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization() +395
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.<InitializeDatabase>b__4(InternalContext c) +11
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input) +110
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action) +214
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase() +97
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +28
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +53
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Include(String path) +18
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.Include(String path) +66
   System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.Include(IQueryable`1 source, String path) +130
   System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.Include(IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 path) +181
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore`6.GetUserAggregateAsync(Expression`1 filter) +259
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore`6.FindByNameAsync(String userName) +536
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager`2.FindByNameAsync(String userName) +56
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.<PasswordSignInAsync>d__29.MoveNext() +101
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.AsyncHelper.RunSync(Func`1 func) +160
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.SignInManagerExtensions.PasswordSignIn(SignInManager`2 manager, String userName, String password, Boolean isPersistent, Boolean shouldLockout) +127
   ProductionMonitor.Account.Login.LogIn(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\newmanr\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ProductionMonitor\Account\Login.aspx.cs:36
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9669962
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +108
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +12
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +15
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
   System.Web.UI.<ProcessRequestMainAsync>d__523.MoveNext() +5911
```

i am going to be writing a simple login for this in the mean time however i would really much like to correct this issue and use identity to ensure it's working correctly.

Thanks,
R

Comment: I copied the app code and pages etc into a new project that had the individual accounts on and this raised many errors but after a short while of powering through and a good amount of Coffee, i cracked it. i am unsure of what the resolution was unfortunately however it is now working.